# How does StackExchange load data from the server without making an XHR request?

Tags: http, ajax, networking, http-request, websockets

When viewing the questions for a tag on SE networks, every now and then you will get a message at the top:

> *n* questions with new activity.

However the weird thing (to me) is that I don't see any network requests made. How exactly is this accomplished?

[image: StackOverflow questions with new activity]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not seeing requests because it's not making any; the page is maintaining an open [Web Socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) connection to the server, and the updates are being *pushed* from the server to your browser, rather than downloaded at your browser's request.

Comment: I had a feeling this is what was happening, but didn't know what it was called. Thanks for the info.